# my dob code wont recognize days above 12 without triggering my input error text

Tags: python

my first code i have written whilst learning, and have become stuck on one issue.

```
    NAME=str(input("Enter your name: "))
    print ("hello",NAME)

    from datetime import *


    today = date.today()
    print("Today: " +  today.strftime('%A %d, %b %Y'))
    good_value = False
    value = ""

    while good_value == False:
        value = input("Insert Date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")

        try:
            datetime.strptime(value, '%m/%d/%Y')
            good_value = True

        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Date format invalid.")


    thisYear = today.year
    dob_data = value.split("/")
    dobDay = int(dob_data[0])
    dobMonth = int(dob_data[1])
    ÁdobYear = int(dob_data[2])
    dob = date(thisYear,dobMonth,dobDay)

    if today == date(thisYear,dobMonth,dobDay):
            print ("happy bithday", NAME)
    else:
            print ("its not your birthday, sucks to be you")
```

when i run the code it will work perfectly unless i type the date being over the 12th, so not breaking the error loop and obviously limiting the dates that can be put into the finished product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
value = input("Insert Date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
```

you are informing user that format should be DD/MM/YYYY, but here

```
datetime.strptime(value, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

you are expecting MM/DD/YYYY. In order to repair this replace former using

```
value = input("Insert Date in format mm/dd/yyyy: ")
```

and

```
dobDay = int(dob_data[0])
dobMonth = int(dob_data[1])
```

using

```
dobDay = int(dob_data[1])
dobMonth = int(dob_data[0])
```

Observe that this did worked for values equal or less than 12 as there are 12 months

Comment: thankyou, mate . guessing it took you seconds to figure that one out

Comment: @arthurcrumplin if you get value out of sensible range or nonsensical limit when working with `datetime` first thing to do is to check if you did not make mistake in format string, be especially careful with *case*, as for example `%m` is zero-padded month whilst `%M` is zero-padded minute, as many people need to use these but not enough often to memorize it, special page is prepared where you might look up meaning of codes https://strftime.org/